# Program is not outputting expected results (python)

Tags: python

new to programming. In python I was tinkering around and wrote a program as follows:

```
from random import randint 
n = 0
m = 0
list = []
sum_list = []

while m < 50:
    while n < 1000:
        random = randint(1, 10000)
        if random < 5000:
            list.append("a")
            n = n + 1
        else:
            n = n + 1
    sum_list.append(len(list))
    del list[:]
    m = m + 1
print(sum(sum_list) / len(sum_list))
```

Should this not print something that tends toward 500? It keeps tending towards 10.

My goal was to look at how probabilities behaved when given larger and larger numbers of iterations. I wanted the program here to take a random integer between 1 and 10,000 and evaluate if it was less than 5000. If yes, append an element to list, and in either case (yes, no), increment n to n +1. Then append the len(list) to sum_list. Iterate this 50 times. Then take sum_list / len(sum_list) to get a result. Shouldn't sum_list be a list of 50 ~500's and len(sum_list) be 50? To get ~500?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the value of `n` at the start of the second iteration of the outer loop, you should see the problem.

(Almost *any* amount of debugging should have pointed you to this, by the way.)

Answer (score 0):

This happened because you forgot to reset value of n which you are iterating over again inside while loop which will run only once among 50 iterations. As `n` is already reached at max value your condition doesn't satisfy and hence you are not getting the expected output.

just add the below line after you deleting a list:

```
n = 0  # reset value
```

As you are new to programming I'd like to point out some of the optional things you need to take care of:

- Avoid using optional keywords like `list` the keyword itself used to initialize empty list or construct list from iterables
- similarly, you are using module `random` and also creating a variable with the same name

Here's an alternate implementation where you can avoid using a list to keep track of number of values lesser than `5000`:

```
from random import randint
m = 0
expected_val = 0

while m < 50:
    m += 1  # increment by one
    n = 0  # initialize at each iteration
    while n < 1000:
        random = randint(1, 10000)
        if random < 5000:
            expected_val += 1  # increment values lesser than 5000
        n = n + 1
print(expected_val/m)  # it's obvious that if you were appending only once to append single value in sum_list in every iteration then it's length would be equal to m which is 50
```